# Replace string specific column with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i'm writing a script to modify csv file.
Here's my format file:

> "id","type","date","release","version"
>   "1","Security Update","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"
>   "2","Bug Fix","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"
>   "3","Enhancement","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"

I'd like to change "Security Update" to "High" , "Bug Fix" to "Medium" and "Enhancement" to "Normal"

Does anyone give me an idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: You should use awk for this.  Read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This replace every instance of the keyword with the replacement you want, in the whole file.

```
awk '{gsub(/Security Update/,"High")}; 1'
awk '{gsub(/Bug Fix/,"Medium")}; 1'
awk '{gsub(/Enhancement/,"Normal")}; 1'
```

Note however, it will match the keywords even if they are not in the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Given this example file:

```
"id","type","date","release","version"
"1","Security Update","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"
"2","Bug Fix","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"
"3","Enhancement","2014-09-23","1.3-0.1","2"
```

It is very easy in to change with Python:

```
$ python -c '
import csv, fileinput
update={"Security Update": "High", "Bug Fix": "Medium", "Enhancement":"Normal"}
for line in csv.reader(fileinput.input()):
    if line[1] in update: line[1]=update[line[1]]
    print ",".join(repr(e) for e in line)' file.csv 
'id','type','date','release','version'
'1','High','2014-09-23','1.3-0.1','2'
'2','Medium','2014-09-23','1.3-0.1','2'
'3','Normal','2014-09-23','1.3-0.1','2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sed.

```
sed 's/Security Update/High/g;s/Bug Fix/Medium/g;s/Enhancement/Normal/g'
```